# So searching only works with loadonce:true?

Tags: jqgrid

That's the only way I could get it work, both for NavGrid or filterToolbar.
Reloading has no effect from server side , even if I'm sure that the resulting json data is correct.
Am I wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have implemented searching on the server side you don't need to use `loadonce: true`. Die implementation of Advanced Searching for example consist from analyzing of `filters` parameter which can be send to the server as the part of request to fill the grid. The format of `filters` parameter is described [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aadvanced_searching#options). If you would use `stringResult: true` parameter of [filterToolbar](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3atoolbar_searching#calling_convention) then you will have the same format of input data in both Advanced Searching and Toolbar filtering.

Comment: Thanks Oleg, very kind of you

Comment: @Kino: You are welcome! I hope I expressed me clear: the method on the server which provide the data for jqGrid can has parameters `string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows, bool _search, string filters`. So you can first sort the data corresponds to `sidx` and `sord`, then filter the data corresponds to `_search` and `filters` and page the result corresponds to `page` and `rows`. Alternatively you can only sort the data and return *all* data. In the case you should add `loadonce: true` option to jqGrid.